# Python eval does not use locals() where called from nor locals() passed to eval for func

Tags: python, eval

```
def one():
    var1 = 1

    def sub():
        nonlocal var1
        var1 += 1
        return var1

    return sub


def two():
    var1 = 5
    sub1 = one()
    return eval('sub1()', globals(), locals())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(two())
```

I was expecting the above code to print 6 but it prints 2. The Python 3.6.1 docs state: "The expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression (technically speaking, a condition list) using the globals and locals dictionaries as global and local namespace. "

Do the global and local namespaces only apply to what can be parsed in eval? The function call sub1() is evaluated in the namespace of the sub1() function regardless of global or local being passed to eval?

Comment: So you were expecting `nonlocal` in `sub` to refer to the local scope of `two`, not of `one`? The closure of `sub` has already been set to contain `1` before you pass it to `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the global and local namespaces pretty much only apply to those that can be parsed in `eval`. Function objects are statically bound to their global object (the module!) and when a function is entered, a new local namespace is created.

Answer (score 1):

`nonlocal` refers to a parent scope of the function's *definition*, not the *call site*. When you pass locals into `eval`, you're not changing the local variables inside of functions you call — you're setting up local variables for the code snippet you're evaluating. So writing `eval('sub1()', globals(), locals()` is equivalent to just writing `sub1()`, because the same local variables are in scope either way — and you wouldn't expect sub1 to return 6 if you wrote that, would you?

Comment: Did the linking at compile time change in Python? Your comment makes sense but I recall eval was more useful the last time I used it which was in python 2.

Comment: @Buoy: Python 2 doesn't even have nonlocal, so I think you may have been doing something pretty different in whatever case you're thinking of. But the closest equivalent, *reading* a variable from a function's parent scope, hasn't changed between 2 and 3 (you can see this by changing your code to have `def sub(): return var1 + 1` and running it in Python 2). This is basically just how lexical scoping works — having the code in the OP print 6 would imply dynamic scope, which no version of Python I know of has.